# where can I order chalav yisroel lactose online?

Tags: product-recommendation, chalav-yisrael-jewishmilk

I would like to brew a milk stout. The way this is done is by adding lactose which is a sugar derived from milk. This adds sweetness in the form of a sugar which does not ferment. Adding other sugars would not work as they would ferment out and rather than adding richness and sweetness to the beer they would make it dry.

Where can I order online chalav yisroel lactose?

Comment: Does it have to be _chalav Yisrael_, or is pareve okay?

Comment: I don't think this is a product that can be parve. it is a derivative of milk

Comment: Anyone look into this?